# Can you build layouts inside of fragements in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I'm a bit new to Android and very new to Fragments. I'm attempting to port an application from Activities to Fragments (well, Activities + Fragments) for Honeycomb. Before we get to the tablet screens, we want to have our app working with the Fragment Compatibility Library for 1.6+ devices. I've read the documentation and examples from Google and nothing explicitly says I can or cannot do the following, but it is not working for me.

The first screen ported is the launcher screen, which has a layout file called fragment_splash.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_background">
    <fragment class="...StartupFragmentLayout$StartupFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragStartup" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/debugText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="DEBUG ON"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowRadius="2"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="bottom">
           ...
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, this does not work. I get an error stating that StartupFragmentLayout$StartupFragment did not create a view. I'm beginning to suspect that I can't nest anything inside the `<fragment>`, since I haven't seen it done in any documentation or examples. Is this correct, or is my problem something else?

Comment: Since you mention you're using the Fragment Compatibility Library, the first thing to check would be that the Activity that you're attempting to use for the splash screen is extended from FragmentActivity.  If that is the case, and you're still getting the error, could you post the exact error message and/or stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Fragment Compatibility Library. The error says "StartupFragmentLayout$StartupFragment did not create a view" and it occurs at setContentView(R.layout.fragment_splash); in OnCreate

Comment: In that case, I'd check out PJL's response below - it seems more in line with the way Fragments are intended to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the documentation whether you can have child views in a `<fragment>`. Given none of the fragment samples do this then I suspect it is not the way that they are meant to be used. You could try changing `<fragment>` into a `<FrameLayout>` and adding the fragment into it at run-time if you really want to, to see if that works.

However, I think your best solution is to put your child views into a separate layout file and then in `onCreateView` inflate into the fragment's container via say:

```
final View iv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favourites, container, false);
```

I don't think that you will lose anything as a result of doing it this way.

Comment: I think you accidentally a word. What did you mean with the sentence "You could try changing into a and adding the fragment into it at run-time if you really want to, to see if that works."

Comment: @CACuzcatlan it should say ."..changing <fragment> into a <FrameLayout>" which I can see on my screen.

Comment: I see it now, not sure if you edited it or if my browser was acting up yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Just to tie this off, fragments can not have children in layouts. PJL is suggesting the right approach. The layout inside a fragment should be specified in a separate XML file. You can then inject this layout into the view tree by returning it from the fragments onCreateView method.